# SQL geography::EnvelopeAggregate output not accurate

Tags: sql, sql-server, spatial, geography

I am trying to get the geography::EnvelopeAggregate for a set of locations. The geography column values are calculated using the Lat/Long for individual points.
When I try to fetch the boundary box(Extent) the box does not cover all the individual points. Is this expected behaviour? Can someone who has expertise in this field provide some inputs.
Below is the SQL code and corresponding Map plotted.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..[#ServicePoints]'))
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #Points
    END
CREATE TABLE #Points
(
    PointId nvarchar(max),
    Lat float,
    Long float,
    Location geography
)
insert into #Points(PointId, Lat, Long, Location)
values ('point1', 47.659226, -117.218292, geography::Point(47.659226, -117.218292, 4326))
insert into #Points(PointId, Lat, Long, Location)
values ('point2', 47.659226, -117.218292, geography::Point(47.659226, -117.218292, 4326))
insert into #Points(PointId, Lat, Long, Location)
values ('point3', 47.659226, -117.218292, geography::Point(47.659226, -117.218292, 4326))
insert into #Points(PointId, Lat, Long, Location)
values ('point3', 47.658276, -117.218474, geography::Point(47.658276, -117.218474, 4326))
insert into #Points(PointId, Lat, Long, Location)
values ('point3', 47.658323, -117.21899, geography::Point(47.658323, -117.21899, 4326))
insert into #Points(PointId, Lat, Long, Location)
values ('point3', 47.658341, -117.219487, geography::Point(47.658341, -117.219487, 4326))
insert into #Points(PointId, Lat, Long, Location)
values ('point3', 47.660115, -117.219365, geography::Point(47.660115, -117.219365, 4326))
insert into #Points(PointId, Lat, Long, Location)
values ('point3', 47.658478, -117.216265, geography::Point(47.658478, -117.216265, 4326))

select * from #Points
--select geography::Point(47.658323, -117.21899, 4326)
Select E1.ID, 
                   E1.SPEXtents.STPointN(3).Lat as BottomLeft_Lat, 
                   E1.SPEXtents.STPointN(3).Long as BottomLeft_Long,
                   E1.SPEXtents.STPointN(1).Lat as RightTop_Lat,         
                   E1.SPEXtents.STPointN(1).Long as RightTop_Long, 
                   E1.SPExtents.STPointN(2).Lat as BottomRight_Lat,
                   E1.SPExtents.STPointN(2).Long as BottomRight_Long,
                   E1.SPExtents.STPointN(4).Lat as TopRight_Lat,
                   E1.SPExtents.STPointN(4).Long as TopRight_Long

        from
        (SELECT 1 as ID,
                geography::EnvelopeAggregate(sp.Location) AS SPExtents
        FROM #Points sp
        ) E1;
```

And the representation of these points in map is below. As can be seen 2 points are lying outside the boundary.
[image: 2 Points lying outside the extents.]

OR Should I be plotting a circle connecting these 4 coordinates? In which case I can see that all the points fall within the circle as shown.
[image: Circle plotted using the coordinates]

[image: Circle]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on some rough testing, it looks like EnvelopeAggregate returns a circular area. I found this with the following:

```
select geography::EnvelopeAggregate(sp.Location).ToString() AS SPExtents
FROM #Points sp
```

If you want to see the actual area described by that, just remove the `.ToString()` from the above.